# Rename pdf-tron tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Could you please rename [pdf-tron](/questions/tagged/pdf-tron) tag to [pdftron](/questions/tagged/pdftron). This was a typo and there is only one assoc post on SO. Thank you!

Comment: any particular reason?  it is a lot easier to read when hyphenated.

Comment: @psubsee2003 The official name is "PDFtron", so I think that the OP's request is a good one.

Comment: @BlueIce We tend not to care about what the official name is. The official name can use capital letters - our tag names cannot. Readability will always win here.

Comment: @animuson Good to know! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: pdf-tron is a typo. It is not supposed to be 2 words, only one. The tag stands for pdftron.com not something else. You would not tag android as and-roid etc Thank you!

Comment: I renamed this at the request of our advertising team.  It would be good for you to create [pdftron's tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdftron/info) to better inform users of the tag.